# How to compute how much object was rotated clockwise relative to specific plain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, virtual-reality, quaternions

Working on my VR project, so
There is an object - a representation of hand in VR, i.e. it can turn in any direction.
There is another object - a kind of keyhole in the door, into which you can insert a key and turn it by your hand.
Im trying to figure out how to calculate the angle that the hand made clockwise relative to a keyhole (on which angle you turned a hand with a key, speaking otherwise).

I tried to calculate this as head-on, creating two virtual points, one of which moved with the controller when its turning and then calculating the distance between these points (caused various problems associated with turning the hand in the other direction), and tried using various operations on quaternions and vectors, but due to lack of knowledge, i cant build a correct algorithm.
I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi there. Let's say your key's orientation for x axis is K and your keyhole 's orientation for x axis is H. To know it's relative orientation you should take K from H and get let's say G. Simply speaking G=H-K. That will give you orientation that it was turned. You could use that to know how many degrees it did turn. If G is positive then it's clockwise. If it's negative then counterclockwise or vice versa (depends on your world. You could check degrees like this if (G>45)OpenDoor (); or something like that. Let me know if you understood or need full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be pretty straightforward with [vector3.angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html). Supossing index finger is hand's z axis, and y looks up, you can track how much the y local y axis rotates.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AngleExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 startingHandUp;

    void Update()
    {
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(startingHandUp, transform.up);

        if (angle > 90f)
            print("opened door");
    }
}
```